# running aapt binary on shared hosting

Tags: linux

I want to run the aapt binary on my shared hosting so that I can use it in some scripts. I have installed aapt locally (`sudo apt install aapt`), and uploaded it to my `home/user/bin` folder on shared hosting with execute bit set. When I run it via ssh I get this error:

`aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libaapt.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

So I find which library files are required locally for aapt, gather and zip them. Upload and extract them to `home/user/lib` folder.

```
zip -j libs.zip $(ldd /usr/bin/aapt | grep "=>" | sed -e "s/(.*//" -e "s/.*=> //")
```

When I execute aapt now on shared hosting (or any other command for that matter) I get a segmentation fault.

So I move all the library files to `home/user/lib/aapt` and execute aapt. Each time I get an error for a missing lib file, I move the missing library back up to the `home/user/lib` folder until I have the following:

```
lib:
aapt/
lib7z.so
libaapt.so.0
libandroidfw.so.0
libbacktrace.so.0
libbase.so.0
libcutils.so.0
liblog.so.0
libpng16.so.16
libunwind.so.0
libutils.so.0
libziparchive.so.0

lib/aapt:
libc.so.6*
libexpat.so.1
libgcc_s.so.1
libm.so.6
libpthread.so.0*
libstdc++.so.6
libz.so.1
```

When I run aapt now I get the following errors:

```
aapt: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by aapt)
aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by aapt)
aapt: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /home/user/lib/libaapt.so.0)
aapt: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /home/user/lib/libaapt.so.0)
aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /home/user/lib/libaapt.so.0)
aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by /home/user/lib/libutils.so.0)
aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /home/user/lib/libutils.so.0)
aapt: /lib64/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by /home/user/lib/libpng16.so.16)
aapt: /lib64/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.3.4' not found (required by /home/user/lib/libpng16.so.16)
aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /home/user/lib/libpng16.so.16)
aapt: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by /home/user/lib/libandroidfw.so.0)
aapt: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by /home/user/lib/libandroidfw.so.0)
aapt: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /home/user/lib/libandroidfw.so.0)
aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /home/user/lib/libandroidfw.so.0)
aapt: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by /home/user/lib/liblog.so.0)
aapt: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.5' not found (required by /home/user/lib/liblog.so.0)
aapt: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /home/user/lib/liblog.so.0)
aapt: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /home/user/lib/liblog.so.0)
aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /home/user/lib/liblog.so.0)
aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /home/user/lib/libcutils.so.0)
aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by /home/user/lib/libcutils.so.0)
aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /home/user/lib/libbacktrace.so.0)
aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by /home/user/lib/libbacktrace.so.0)
aapt: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /home/user/lib/libbacktrace.so.0)
aapt: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /home/user/lib/libbacktrace.so.0)
aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /home/user/lib/libziparchive.so.0)
aapt: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /home/user/lib/libziparchive.so.0)
aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /home/user/lib/libbase.so.0)
aapt: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by /home/user/lib/libbase.so.0)
aapt: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /home/user/lib/libbase.so.0)
aapt: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /home/user/lib/libbase.so.0)
aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /home/user/lib/libunwind.so.0)
aapt: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /home/user/lib/lib7z.so)
aapt: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /home/user/lib/lib7z.so)
aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /home/user/lib/lib7z.so)
```

If I move the libc.so.6 or libstdc++.so.6 files into the lib folder, I get the segmentation fault again because they interfere with the host system library files which I presume are dependent on another version.

This is where I am stuck and my question is how do I make the aapt binary point to the different libraries in the aapt folder?

I preferably don't want to do any recompiling as a static binary as this is out of my scope of abilities and wish to keep it that way for the time being.

Comment: What's up Mr. Cryptic Sponge Bob.... Could this be an x86 vs x64 type issue? If you have not already considered or looked into that, maybe that's worth a simple look to verify, etc. Cool!!

Comment: Host is x64 and workstation is x64. Typing uname -mpi gives same result: x86_64 x86_64 x86_64

Comment: I guess I was referring to the libraries as well as the host and client CPU architecture. I read some issues are resolved by ensuring the x86 libraries are available too (or x64) vice versa where/if/when applicable, etc. But otherwise it may be something like this you are in need of potentially so look it over in case it helps too. . . https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24811/changing-linked-library-for-a-given-executable-centos-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I got it working!
Initially I wrote a script that used apktool to decompile the apk and extract the information that I required (apk label and version number), but the process although functional was rather slow, taking about 5 or 6 seconds per apk. I then discovered a perl module to get aapt running on the host by following instructions [here](https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/exodus-tool-safely-copy-linux-binaries/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` that contains the directory the `.so` files you uploaded from your local system.

```
user@host:~$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/lib/ /path/to/aapt ...
```

You can check to see if `aapt` is finding them and if so where using `ldd /path/to/appt/binary`

But it also looks as if some system `.so` files are mis-matched versions, so you may have a LOT more file finding an uploading to do from your local system.

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH is already set to /home/user/lib. If I place any library files there, or add another folder to the path, the main system also takes these folders as a priority over existing ones so not an option. I know it is possible to compile a program to look to a specified folder for its libraries, but compiling isn't the route I wish to travel and may as well make a static version.

Comment: @5p0ng3b0b that is why you change your lib path in one instance of one shell and run your program - rest of system retains default.  Good luck!

Comment: I am using ssh shell. Still get seg fault when running aapt after changing LD_LIBRARY PATH. Even if It did work running that way, the other commands would seg fault in the script. I have now managed to make a working static binary using ermine but will only last for 30 days. I will persevere!